# encodeURIComponent() vs JSON.stringify() in data-* attribute

Tags: javascript, json

I'd like to use array as `data-*` attribute and a lot of StackOverflow answers suggest that I should use `JSON.stringify()`;

- [How to pass an array into jQuery .data() attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071618/how-to-pass-an-array-into-jquery-data-attribute)
- [Store and use an array using the HTML data tag and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287462/store-and-use-an-array-using-the-html-data-tag-and-jquery)
- https://gist.github.com/charliepark/4266921
- etc.

So, if I have this array: `['something', 'some\'thing', 'some"thing']` it will be parsed to `"["something","some'thing","some\"thing"]"` and therefore it won't fit neither `data-*=''` nor `data-*=""` because either `'` or `"` will break the HTML tag.

Am I missing something or `encodeURIComponent()` is a true solution to encoding arrays like that? Why in other StackOverflow answers nobody noticed this?

Comment: Do you want to generate HTML code _using_ JavaScript, or why are you asking about `encodeURIComponent` …?

Comment: you can simply tack a property onto an element, including arrays. that would prevent complications from parsing html.

Comment: No, I just want to put a value that uses both `"` and `'` as a value of a `data-*` attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reasoning that `JSON.stringify` is *not* guaranteed to be safe in HTML attributes *when* the text is part of the HTML markup itself is valid. However, there is no escaping issue if using one of the access methods (eg. `.data` or `.attr`) to assign the value as these do not directly manipulate raw HTML text.

While `encodeURIComponent` *would* "work" as it escapes all the problematic characters, it both results in overly ugly values/markup and requires a manual `decodeURIComponent` step when consuming the values - yuck!

Instead, if inserting the data directly into the HTML, simply "html encode" the value and use the result as the attribute value. Such a function comes with most server-side languages, although an equivalent is not supplied natively with JavaScript.

Assuming the attribute values are quoted, the problematic characters that *need* to be replaced with the appropriate HTML entities are:

- `&amp;` - `&`, escape-the-escape, applied first
- `&quot;` - `"`, for double-quoted attribute
- `&apos;` - `'`, for single-quoted attribute
- Optional (required for XML): `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Using the above approach relies on the parsing *of* the HTML markup, and the automatic decoding of HTML entities therein, such that the *actual* (non-encoded) result is stored as the data-attribute value in the DOM.

Comment: In case you need to display the JSON data in `<textarea>`, you might want to replace the single quote with `\u0027` and double quote with `\u0022` instead HTML entities, because `&quot;` will show as it is in `<textarea>`.

Comment: > simply "html encode" the value. Neglects to provide an example on how to do that.

Comment: @AlxVallejo The language/environment generating the JSON has not been specified. "_Such a function comes with most server-side languages_, .."; of which most can be found when searching.

Comment: @user2864740 ok, well you cited `encodeURIComponent` which is JavaScript. So what would you use instead?

Comment: `encodeURIComponent` was referenced by the original post so it warranted to be be mentioned specifically; per the answer, JavaScript has no such method defined (as per the ECMAScript specification or the W3C DOM), although one could find one of many 3rd-party libraries that do. Again, depends on context.

Comment: but what if you need to both access the attribute from javascript *and* from innerHTML? it seems no matter how I encode, I can't get *both* to work.