# How can I set an array of items in the html part of my Riot.js component?

Tags: javascript, arrays, riot.js

I want to declare dynamic lists in the html tags of my riot component, but can't figure out what am I doing wrong. Found this syntax for the array in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287462/store-and-use-an-array-using-the-html-data-tag-and-jquery?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), but in a different context. So here's what I've been trying:

```
<c-artworkdisplay
     extras= '[
         { "extra_name": "Featured on xy","extra_source": "xy.com" },
         { "extra_name": "Featured on zw","extra_source": "zw.com" }
     ]'>
</c-artworkdisplay>
```

The .tag itself should be fine as I could manage this to work when the array was declared in the mount script (I need the list to be unique for each tag, so that's not an option).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your tag from

```
<c-artworkdisplay
     extras= '[
         { "extra_name": "Featured on xy","extra_source": "xy.com" },
         { "extra_name": "Featured on zw","extra_source": "zw.com" }
     ]'>
</c-artworkdisplay>
```

to

```
<c-artworkdisplay extras='{extras}'></c-artworkdisplay>
```

The **extras** will be our **list** which will be updated dynamically.

and define your **list extras** before mounting tag.

```
this.extras = [
  { 
    extra_name: 'Featured on xy',
    extra_source: 'xy.com' 
  },
  { 
    extra_name: 'Featured on zw',
    extra_source: 'zw.com' 
  }
];

riot.mount('c-artworkdisplay');
```

The tag will start reading content from the defined extras variable.
After changing the content of extras don't forget to call `riot.update()` function.

```
 this.extras.push({
    extra_name: 'Test',
    extra_source: 'test.com' 
});

riot.update();
```

In the link, you can see illustrated example for your situation.

https://codepen.io/alihuseyn/pen/dmaRab

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks so much for helping out, it's a lifesaver :)