# I need to filter a list with a button that is passed multiple terms

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am working on some code created by someone else and need to adjust it to include more terms.

The page has buttons that filters a list of doctors based on specialties but the terms are not all the same. Here is the code for the button:

```
<button class="doctor data-filter-button" data-filter="specialties" data-value="oculofacial">Med Spa / Oculoplastics</button>
```

This works for filtering based on the term 'oculofacial' but I also need it to include the term 'oculoplastic-surgery'. I attempted to pass multiple values into the data-value tag but it didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to SO, I would recommend checking out [mcve] as that will help you in getting the best assistance available.

Comment: Whether passing multiple values, and how they are to be separated, depends entirely on the code that deals with that data attribute. Without seeing that there is no way we can help you I’m afraid.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Store and use an array using the HTML data tag and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287462/store-and-use-an-array-using-the-html-data-tag-and-jquery)   you don't actually need jquery just use valid json

Comment: also, you may have multiple data-items